# mandar por ajax el parametro id de un path en twig, symfony5

Tags: symfony5

Queria obtener por ajax un parametro que tengo que enviar por una ruta en twig. El parametro (id) se obtiene correctamente por ajax y se envia corectamente a la plantilla (comprobado). Pero no se como añadirlo a la ruta desde jquery.
Este es el codigo de la funcion del controlador que envia los parametros a ajax.

```
/**
     *
     * @Route("/source", options={"expose"=true},name="source", methods={"GET","POST"})
     */
    public function source(Request $request,ProductoRepository $productoRepository): Response
    {               
        $producto=$request->request->get('color');
        $productoColor = $productoRepository->findOneBy(['id' => $producto]);
        if ($request->isXMLHttpRequest()) 
        {         
            return new JsonResponse(['productoAjax'=>$productoColor->getId(),'imagenAjax'=>$productoColor->getImagen(),'precioAjax'=>$productoColor->getPrecio()]);
        }
    return new Response('This is not ajax!', 400);
    }
```

el id esta en al variable `productoAjax`
Este es el codigo del jquery del ajax:

```
$(document).on("change",'.color', function(event) { 
    var Ruta=Routing.generate("source");
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url:Ruta,
    data: {color: $('.color:checked').val()},
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(response) {
        $("#foto").attr('src', response['imagenAjax']);            
        $("#precio").html(response['precioAjax']);
        $("#comprar").attr("href",path('comprar',{'id': response['productoAjax']}));
    }
});
});
```

donde se deberia enviar al `href` del `link` con id `comprar`.
y este es el codigo de la plantilla que contiene el `link` `comprar` y que debe recibir los valores del ajax.

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}
    {% include "armonicas/header.html.twig" %}
    <div class="container-fluid">
        {% for producto in productos %}
            <div class="row p-5">
                <div class="col-12 text-center">
                    <h4>{{ producto.nombre }}</h4>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row  justify-content-center align-items-center p-3">
                <div class="col-4 text-right  mr-3">
                    <img id="foto" class= "border productoPaginaPrincipal" src="{{ producto.imagen }}">
                </div>
                <div class="col-4 ml-3">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-12">
                            {% for color in colores %}
                                <div><input type="radio" id="color" class="color" name="color" value="{{ color.id }}"><label for='color'>{{ color.color }}</label></div>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div clas="row">
                        <div class="col-12 d-inline-flex">                           
                            <div id="precio">{{ producto.precio }}</div><div> € </div>                           
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div clas="row">
                        <div class="col-12">                           
                            <div><a id="comprar" class="btn btn-success" href="{{ path('comprar',{'id': producto.id}) }}">Comprar</a></div>                           
                        </div>
                    </div>    
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>

</div>
{% endblock %}
{% block javascripts %}
    {{ parent() }}
    <script src="{{ asset('bundles/fosjsrouting/js/router.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ path('fos_js_routing_js', { callback: 'fos.Router.setData' }) }}"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

pero no funciona. En la ruta siempre se envia el id del producto que se carga inicialmente, y no el que se carga por ajax. Tanto la imagen como el precio se cargan perfectamente por ajax.

Comment: a ver a ver si entiendo: lo que deseas hacer es una llamada ajax a un controlador para obtener un parámetro y si esta es satisfactoria, entonces completar una ruta para hacer otra llamada ajax???

Comment: No se está un poco mezclado todo, pero se me ocurre decirle a JSRouting que tambien genera a ´comprar´ y poder hacer:$("#comprar").attr("href",Routing.generate("comprar", {'id':response.productoAjax}));

Comment: perfecto Francisco, me sirvio. Muchas gracias.